# Google sheets: Case statement or ifelse formula to modify a cell's value based on the value of another cell?

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, formula, case-statement

1. Based on a validation, if A1 = 20, then B1 = 5.
2. Based on a formula, B2 = B1.

Except, I want B2 = B1 + D1, if C1 = True.

My question is: How do I make it so that the formula for one cell (B2) equals the sum of two cells (B1,D1) in the event that a third cell (C1) has a True value? If it is False, I want it (B2) to just equal the sum of one cell (B1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in B2:

```
=B1+IF(C1="True",D1,0)
```

If C1 is TRUE then it can be shortened to:

```
=B1+IF(C1,D1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: This is correct. Thank you. Is there a way to display this value with a '+' before it?

Comment: Yes but it would change it to a text string that then cannot be used in other formulas or you could put a custom number format through the ribbon of `"+"0`

Comment: @JakeLivsey look into what Tom just put.  It is a custom format that will put the + and the - when needed.

Comment: Scott's method would only add a superficial + in front of the returned value. In cases where the returned value would be negative, that would be undesired. Tom's method is grammatically/mathematically correct, however "+0" was desired, so I went with a custom number format of +0;-0 which created the desired effect. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

```
=if(C1=true,sum(B1,D1),sum(B1))
```

[image]